# Erlang list of tuples with another list of tuples inside to a single list

Tags: list, dictionary, erlang, tuples

So, i'm searching for a nice way to do this.

Incoming data is something like (it can be much more than example, but only one sublevel):

```
[
  [
    {d1, "1"}, 
    {d2, "2"}, 
    {sub_data,
      [
        {d1, "3"},
        {d2, "4"}
      ]
    }
  ], 
  [
    {d1, "5"},
    {d2, "6"}
  ]
]
```

I need to serialize this to:

> [{"1", "2"}, {"> 3", "> 4"}, {"5", "6"}]

Now i'm doing it like this, which is not a great way imo:

```
lists:map(fun(Data) ->
    [{f:g(d1, Data), f:g(d2, Data)}] ++
    [{"> " ++ f:g(d1, SubData)}, {"> " ++ f:g(d2, SubData)} 
     || SubData <- f:g(sub_data, Data)], 
    Data
).
```

Comment: The logic behind your example is quite hard to generalize, I would expect something like `[["1", "2", "> 3", "> 4"], ["5", "6"]]` or `[["1", "2", ["> 3", "> 4"]], ["5", "6"]]` or `[["1", "2", ["3", "4"]], ["5", "6"]]`

Comment: Well, it's a list of tuples {id, name} for an element in nitrogen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've come up with:

```
transform(Input) ->
        lists:flatten(lists:map(fun(Item) -> transform_item(Item, []) end, Input)).

transform_item(Item, Prefix) ->
        {KVs, SubDatas} = lists:partition(fun({sub_data, _}) -> false;
                                             (_) -> true
                                          end, Item),
        Res0 = list_to_tuple(lists:map(fun({_, Value}) -> Prefix ++ Value end, KVs)),
        [Res0, lists:map(fun({sub_data, SubItem}) -> transform_item(SubItem, "> ") end, SubDatas)].

test() ->
        case transform([[{d1, "1"}, {d2, "2"}, {sub_data, [{d1, "3"}, {d2, "4"}]}], [{d1, "5"}, {d2, "6"}]]) of
                [{"1", "2"}, {"> 3", "> 4"}, {"5", "6"}] -> io:format("SUCCESS");
                InvalidResult -> io:format("FAILED. Result=~p", [InvalidResult])
        end.
```

Answer (score 0):

What I mean in my comment, is that it is difficult to know how the input can be generalized. for example it is possible to imagine that your input is defined as a list of element which have the structure:

```
[{d1,V},{d2,V}] or
[{d1,V},{d2,V},{subdata,[{d1,V},{d2,V}]}]
```

in this case you could transform with the function:

```
1> F = fun(L) -> lists:reverse(lists:foldl(
            fun([{_,V1},{_,V2},{sub_data,[{_,V3},{_,V4}]}],Acc) -> [{"> " ++ V3,"> " ++ V4},{V1,V2}|Acc];
               ([{_,V1},{_,V2}],Acc) -> [{V1,V2}|Acc] end,
            [],L)) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.106461118>
2> F([[{d1,"1"},{d2,"2"},{sub_data,[{d1,"3"},{d2,"4"}]}],[{d1,"5"},{d2,"6"}]]).
[{"1","2"},{"> 3","> 4"},{"5","6"}]
3> F([[{d1,"1"},{d2,"2"},{sub_data,[{d1,"3"},{d2,"4"}]}],
      [{d1,"5"},{d2,"6"}],
      [{d1,"7"},{d2,"8"},{sub_data,[{d1,"9"},{d2,"10"}]}]]).
[{"1","2"},{"> 3","> 4"},{"5","6"},{"7","8"},{"> 9","> 10"}]
4>
```

But you don't say if it is possible to have more than 3 tuple in the sublist, if any combination of data and subdata is possible ...
 is it possible to have this input:

```
[
  [
    {d1, "1"}, 
    {d2, "2"}, 
    {sub_data,
      [
        {d1, "3"},
        {d2, "4"}
      ]
    }
    {d3, "2"}, 
  ], 
  [
    {sub_data,
      [
        {d1, "3"},
      ]
    }
    {d1, "5"},
    {d2, "6"}
  ]
]
```

and what should be the expected result?

Comment: The output format, `[{"1", "2"}, {"> 3", "> 4"}, {"5", "6"}]`, doesn't seem very practical either..